# I can't find the error and no error is displayed

Tags: python, web-scraping, printing, jupyter-notebook, screen-scraping

I would like the value from the page to be output with the print() command, but unfortunately no value is output and no error is displayed.

webseite: https://coordvert.com/en/koordinaten-umrechnen/utm/dezimalgrad?utmzone=-1N&utme=668184.607&utmn=0.000

This is the code:

breitengrad = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//div[@class="input-group input-group-sm"])[4]/input').text

print(breitengrad)

Answer (score 0):

That element you are looking for (breitengrad) appears to have an ID, so it's more robust to just locate it by ID. Also, if you are using Selenium 4, the `find_element_*` method was deprecated in favour of `find_element(By.*,...)`.
The following code will accept the cookies in case the initial pop-up shows up, wait for the page to load, locate the `breitengrad` and print out the value:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

url='https://coordvert.com/en/koordinaten-umrechnen/utm/dezimalgrad?utmzone=-1N&utme=668184.607&utmn=0.000'

browser.get(url) 

try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Alles Akzeptieren']"))).click()
except Exception as e:
    print('no pop-up, moving on')

breitengrad = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "cov-2-lat")))
print(breitengrad.get_attribute('value'))
```

This returns the value of that input field:

```
0
```